# fake/mock/background terminal for testing an ncurses application

Tags: testing, terminal, automated-tests, ncurses

I am working with an(other) legacy C application which has a text user interface written using ncurses.

I would like to script some tests of the program running but it will only run in a terminal.
There is no way to remove the user interface.

Is there a way to fake or background a terminal (for the application) without ever having to bring the screen to the foreground?

---

The best I have so far uses screen and timeout as below.
This example performs a timed run of the program.
I've omitted machinery to manage the workspace for brevity.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat - >runmyprogram <<EOF
echo running 
timeout --foreground --preserve-status --signal=HUP 3s cursesprogramcommandlinehere
STATUS=\$?
echo \$STATUS >workspace/exit_status
stty sane
clear
exit \$STATUS
EOF
chmod u+x runmyprogram

screen -dmS foobar /bin/bash

(
    sleep 3
    sleep 1
    screen -S foobar -p 0 -X quit
) &

screen -S foobar -p 0 -X stuff "runmyprogram^M"
screen -r
```

This sort of works but:

- The ncurses application does not start until it is brought to the foreground with `screen -r`.

**I would like to achieve something similar without ever having to use `screen -r`.**

- I have also tried `tmux` but so far have not got this as close to working as `screen`. It also requires a terminal to be attached for the GUI (i.e. tmux attach) to start.
- When tests are run in an Azure build pipeline I get
  "Must be connected to a terminal"

(Adding script /dev/null as suggested [here](https://svennd.be/screen-in-lxc-attach/) causes a hang. I don't see why that would create a terminal anyway)

- This also happens if I run the test with "nohup" which of course does not have a terminal.
- When run from ctest screen also seems to alter the topology of the terminal this runs in when really I want it to be fully isolated.
- There is also at least one race condition as exit_status is not always populated however much time I add between timeout timing out and sending the quit message to screen.

The timeout is necessary to cover (failing) test cases where the TUI does not respond.

I am able to make changes to the legacy application to support this better but rewriting the entire user interface is not an option.

Some related questions:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214715/mocking-a-pseudo-tty-pts
- https://superuser.com/questions/454907/how-to-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach#_=_

---

The difficulty with screen is caused by a subtle interaction between screen and ncurses. I have tried quite a few apps from https://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/Best_ncurses_linux_console_programs as examples and can get them all to work with screen.
The legacy app is the only one that requires screen to be foregrounded. It fails because it makes a call to subwin() which fails and is subsequently treated as a fatal error.
(note this is different behaviour to what I described above. That is, that the app does not start until foregrounded. I have been unable to reproduce this thus far).
The curious bit is that if I attach the screen before I run the application it works. Both the call to subwin() and the rest of the application. **I would like to understand why.**

- I have  tried `tmux` and now got this working. It does not require the window to be attached.

Comment: expect comes to mind: https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: expect by itself won't do it. See https://serverfault.com/a/363776/202472 .
I perhaps need a terminal emulator - like https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.tcl/c/m_YEbavLXow or https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/vlns1m/virterm_001_virtual_offscreen_terminal_for/

Comment: I think I have managed to solve my own problem through the use of [rubber ducks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). To earn the bounty you must improve on my answer (once I get around to posting it).

Comment: Rather than waste the bounty I may award it to any significant improvement/contribution. E.g. explanation of why screen and tmux might be behaving differently for me or an example solution using some other terminal replacement.

Comment: Yet another wasted bounty *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution using [tmux](https://tmuxguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tmux/tmux.html#basic) from bash includes elements as below.

wrapper script to perform a timed run of a program and capture its exit status:

```
cat - >$WSDIR/runprog <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo running program >$WSDIR/stdout
cd $WSDIR
echo 0 >$WSDIR/exit_status
timeout --foreground --preserve-status --signal=HUP $RUNTIME runprogramhere 2>$WSDIR/stderr
STATUS=\$?
echo \$STATUS >$WSDIR/exit_status
stty sane
clear
echo done STATUS=\$STATUS >>$WSDIR/stdout
exit \$STATUS
EOF
chmod u+x $WSDIR/runprog
```

script to run the program using tmux:

```
cat - >$WSDIR/exercise <<EOF
tmux new-session -d -s $SESSIONNAME -x 132 -y 80 "bash -l"
tmux send-keys "cd $WSDIR"
tmux send-keys Enter
tmux send-keys ./runprog
tmux send-keys Enter

# watch for interesting things to happen...

EOF
chmod u+x $WSDIR/exercise
```

Perform a timed run using the script above allowing for things to not work.

```
SESSIONNAME=testFoobar-case1-$$

cleanUp () {
   tmux kill-session $SESSIONNAME 2>/dev/null
}

trap cleanUp 0 TERM

timeout 10s $WSDIR/exercise
```

---

How this works:

- tmux new-session - starts a new session
- -d - starts it detached (so it will work in a script without a 'real' terminal)
- -s - gives us a named session to refer to - so our scripts can tidy up
- tmux send-keys - sends key strokes to the session whether it is in the background or foreground
- timeout is useful to forcing programs to exit if something goes wrong
- --preserve-status forces timeout to preserve the status of the program its running.
- we store the exit status in a file for easy access
- trap invokes the cleanUp routine when we exit
- thus kill-session kills the tmux session on exit
- we generate a unique session name per test script

---

A similar scheme is possible with [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html):

```
screen -S sessionName bash -l
screen -d   - detach the current session
screen -r   - resume a session
screen -S sessionName -X stuff "echo hello^M"  - send keys
```

The differences are minor except screen does not work for the app I am testing.
Tmux has names for special keys. Screen uses control characters instead.

It can be useful to script communications with the tmux (or screen) session using [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) or similar.

Both `tmux` and `screen` have commands to let you take screen shots if that is useful for your tests:

- tmux [capture-pane](https://burnicki.pl/en/2021/07/04/dump-tmux-pane-history-to-a-file.html)
- screen -S sessionName -X -p0 [hardcopy](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Hardcopy.html)