# Why does tmux set TERM=screen?

Tags: terminal, tmux

How does tmux set the terminal to use (as reflected in the TERM environment variable).

For example. If I log in via ssh bash reports:

```
>set | grep TERM
TERM=xterm-256-color
```

If I then run tmux and from within tmux and do the same:

```
>set | grep TERM
TERM=screen
```

I think this is not always the case though since noticing it I have not managed to make tmux say anything else.

This relates to [fake/mock/background terminal for testing an ncurses application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661549/fake-mock-background-terminal-for-testing-an-ncurses-application/74704720#74704720)

Where I am I trying to understand how the terminal emulation affects the resulting behaviour of an ncurses app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tmux sets `TERM` to screen for two reasons:

- tmux (like GNU screen) is a terminal emulator.
- The [`screen`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen) terminal description is close enough to tmux's behavior that it suffices if tmux's [***own***](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-tmux) terminal description is not available.

The manual page *alludes* to these two points, but does not really *explain* them:

> The **`TERM`** environment variable must be set to *‘screen’* or *‘tmux’*
> for all programs running inside tmux.  New windows will automatically have *‘TERM=screen’* added to their environment, but care must be taken not to reset this in shell start-up files.

Applications (other than hard-coded stuff) use terminal descriptions to find how to do similar operations on various terminals.

Since tmux's terminal description has been part of the terminal database since [2015](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20150502), you would only see `TERM=screen` on systems which are either very old, or have only a small subset of the terminal database installed.

Answer (score 2):

That's controlled by the `default-terminal` server option in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

From the [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html):

> default-terminal terminal
> Set the default terminal for new windows created in this
> session - the default value of the TERM environment
> variable.  For tmux to work correctly, this must be set to
> ‘screen’, ‘tmux’ or a derivative of them.

It is considered good practice to not touch the TERM variable directly (do not set it manually in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` but instead rely on tmux to generate it from `.tmux.conf`).